# Trying to install pip3 in Amazon Linux 2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pip, amazon-linux

I did the following and can't get pip3 installed. Any help is appreciated!

```
sudo yum install python3 pip3
Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
Package python3-3.7.9-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 already installed and latest version
No package pip3 available.
Nothing to do
```

I ran sudo yum update previous to this with no issues.

The posts I am finding state that this should work.

This is in the latest AMI on Amazon Linux 2.

I have setup notes from a system I brought up a year ago and this was working then. Did they break something?

Comment: `sudo yum update && sudo yum install python3-pip` (dash, not space).

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-linux.html this should help

Comment: did my solution worked for you?

Answer (score 11):

It is python3-pip. Try the following.

```
sudo yum update && sudo yum install python3-pip
```

Comment: No package python3-pip available

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-install-linux.html). *Invoking Python version 3 directly by using the python3 command instead of python ensures that pip is installed in the proper location, even if an earlier version of Python is present on your system.*

this works for me

- `sudo yum install python37`
- `curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`
- `python3 get-pip.py --user`
- to verify `pip --version`

Comment: No package python37 available

Comment: check your OS derivative, if it is Debian it will 3.7